# What are good vegan diet resources for bicyclists?

Tags: nutrition

I am a vegetarian, and I bike 100-150 miles a week. I see that many cyclists are vegans, and I would love to try a vegan diet compatible with the high energy input that cycling requires.

Can you suggest books, websites and other resources which provide information on healthy and efficient vegan diets for cyclists?

Comment: Depending on how those miles are split over the week and the terrain and riding style (10 race miles are very different than 10 commuting miles), you may not have to do anything.

Comment: My rides are 30-50 miles each, 16-17 m/h on average, with a goal to get to 19-20 m/h in the future

Comment: You might get better answers on fitness.stackexchange.com or lifestyle.stackexchange.com   Here we're more about the machine, this question is about diet with a tangential cycling link, but its not primarily related to riding.  You could substitute any sport or vigorous activity for cycling, and still have the same basic question.  That is why I am voting to close as off-topic for this stack.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's anything particularly unique to your situation to warrant specific diet recommendations. Eat carbs while on the bike, eat what your body feels like when you're off the bike.

You're not self-reporting any actual issues you're having like feeling weak or tired, or having trouble achieving weight goals (e.g., gaining, losing, or maintaining) or fitness goals. So what makes you feel compelled to change something?